# Creating anomaly detection using machine learning

Tags: elasticsearch, machine-learning, anomaly-detection, recurrent-neural-network

I'm very impressed from the new [x-pack](https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/machine-learning) ML of the elastic stack. It seems their technique learns data patterns over time and can predict anomalies in multiple domains.

[image]

Zoomed in:
[image]

I was wondering what approach and network topology could be used, in order to create a similar feature. Is it fair to assume that since x-pack works on time series data, RNN would be a good start?

Interested in your opinions and references.

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213120/machine-learning-algorithms-used-by-elastic-x-pack-plugin/51632375

Answer (score 2):

From what I read, I'd be surprised if they're using neural networks. Here's how they say they detect anomalies:

> Detect outliers in a population by building a profile of a “typical” user or machine to know when one starts to stray from the pack.

Doing anomaly detection like that requires nothing more than a statistical test of whether or not observed behavior is within 2-3 standard deviations of the expected behavior.

If you want to use neural networks for some reason, you could go with CNNs, RNNs, or attention-only networks. [Google recently showed that you don't need RNNs or CNNs to do state-of-the-art translation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762).

Comment: The attention mechanism proposed in the paper, is  just a part of the NN "The encoder is composed of a stack of N = 6 identical layers. Each layer has two
sub-layers. The first is a multi-head self-attention mechanism, and the second is a simple, positionwise
fully connected feed-forward network"

Comment: @RoniGadot, my point was that the OP doesn't necessarily need something complicated like an RNN. Google's network is a feed-forward (no recurrences) network that operates on sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at their Anomaly Detection.  I'm not a math major, but the results have given me goosebumps.  (If only it could send me an alert!  See here: [Do Elastic Anomaly Detection Rules Actually Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76706742/do-elastic-anomaly-detection-rules-actually-work))

I am pretty sure they are not using neural net.  From what I've read, that's a subset of Machine Learning.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34704315)