# Do Elastic Anomaly Detection Rules Actually Work?

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I'm evaluating Elastic (ELK) machine-learning Anomaly Detection.  Seems to work great.  But I can't get the associated "Rule" to work, that's supposed to send an email.

Has anyone ever seen an ELK Anomaly Detection Rule actually send an alert?

Thanks!

I have made other Rules work, and send me an email.  And I can Test the Rule itself over a time frame, and it reports it found anomalies.  The Job itself says it found anomalies.  But the Anomaly Rule itself always says zero alerts were generated.